# How to use image scanner with node.js

Tags: node.js, wrapper, node-webkit, printers, image-scanner

I've seen someone build a [cross-platform node module for accessing and managing print jobs](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer). Is it possible to somehow create a similar module for accessing computer's image scanner? I'd like to create a nice nodewebkit app that would ease the process of scanning lots of paper documents for my users.

Comment: searching "scan" and "scanner" on the npm website comes up with nothing, so I'm going to guess that it doesn't exist

Comment: But if you know enough C++ and have a strong knowledge of how scanners, their protocols, etc work you COULD make your own module. But it'd be very difficult

Comment: Ok, seems like I have to create it myself. BRB :)

Comment: To interact with scanners, check the protocols like TWAIN, WIA etc.

Comment: I've already started taking a god look on them. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @KubaOrlik, did u finished developing it?

Comment: I did manage to scan some files using WIA. I honestly don't know how did I manage to achieve that knowing so little C++. Here's the messy result: https://github.com/kuba-orlik/node-WIA

I abandoned the project as I no longer use Windows.

It might require Visual Studio to compile.